# Pandas conditional Groupby min

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

In the dataframe below, I need `df['output']` to fill in the date for each `df['SubGroup']` conditionally.

`If df['HardDate'] exists for df['SubGroup'], use df['HardDate']`
`elif minimum (earliest) BookDate where df['Values'] is not null.`
and then possibly df.apply the function to achieve desired output.

```
| MainGroup | SubGroup | BookDate  |Values | HardDate   | **Output** |
|-----------|----------|-----------|-------|------------|------------|
| Group1    | SubG1    | 1/1/2000  | Null  | 10/10/2010 | 10/10/2010 |
| Group1    | SubG1    | 2/1/2000  | Null  | 10/10/2010 | 10/10/2010 |
| Group1    | SubG1    | 3/1/2000  | 350   | 10/10/2010 | 10/10/2010 |
| Group1    | SubG1    | 4/1/2000  | 400   | 10/10/2010 | 10/10/2010 |
| Group1    | DiffG2   | 9/1/2012  | 6000  | Null       | 9/1/2012   |
| Group1    | DiffG2   | 10/1/2012 | 7000  | Null       | 9/1/2012   |
| Group1    | DiffG2   | 11/1/2012 | 8000  | Null       | 9/1/2012   |
| Group1    | DiffG2   | 12/1/2012 | 9000  | Null       | 9/1/2012   |
| Group2    | AltG1    | 5/1/1999  | Null  | Null       | 6/1/1999   |
| Group2    | AltG1    | 6/1/1999  | 190   | Null       | 6/1/1999   |
| Group2    | AltG1    | 7/1/1999  | 290   | Null       | 6/1/1999   |
| Group2    | AltG1    | 8/1/1999  | 390   | Null       | 6/1/1999   |
```

I tried the following which pulls min date, but does not include any filter. 
 `df['BookDate'].iloc[df.groupby(by = ['MainGroup','SubGroup'])[‘Book_Date’].idxmin(axis=1)]`

Trying to add a `df['BookDate'].loc[date slice]` results in an error

Comment: is output your expected output column?

Comment: Is your subgroup unique to your dataset or is it only unique to main group?

Comment: @MattR Yes sir, `df['output']` is my expected output column. @Mikhail Venkov The SubGroup is only unique to the MainGroup.

Answer (score 0):

This what I would do:

1. Group By and find minimum date:

`grp_df = df.groupby('SubGroup')['BookDate'].min()`

2. Join back to original df

`df = df.merge(grp_df, right_index = True, left_on = 'SubGroup', how='left')`

3. Populate output column

`df['output'] = df[['HardDate','BookDate']].max(axis=1) #This will pick date over null`

Comment: I can not use `right_index = True` because the index for the existing df is made up by pandas. I also had to convert the grp_df to a dataframe using `.to_frame()` and `.reset_index()` as the grp_df in step 1 is only one column named 'book_date' and an index of 'SubGroup'. I played with the .merge function pretty extensively and still cannot figure out how to get it to join properly as i'm receiving the error: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: I am not sure I understand your issue. In step one you get a dateframe with one column of minimum BookDates and index being SubGroup. When you are doing merging in step 2, the right table is the grp_df. You should use index from right table (hence right_index = True) to join on SubGroup in df. So you shouldn't need to do .to_frame() or .reset_index(). The latter will make joining impossible.